# Binding dropdown list using ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, drop-down-menu

I would like to bind the data from splunk to a dropdown list.

The servlet return a JsonString by gson

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String jsonString = gson.toJson(arrays);
                    resp.getWriter().write(jsonString);
```

In the jsp, ajax was used to get back the jsonString and blind in drop down list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "../getName",

            success : function(data) {
            console.log("success to return name");
            if (msg) {
                      alert("Somebody" + name + " was added in list !");
                      location.reload(true);
             } else {
                      alert("Cannot add to list !");
             }

             $.each(objdata["wlsDomain"], function(i, val) {
             jQuery('#DropdownList').append('<option value="' + val.name  + '</option>');
             }); 

        };
    )};     
 )];
```

It said $(...).ready is not a function. If I change the "$" to "jQuery", then there is no warning. However, binding is failed.

Then I have also tried the below code for knowing whether the ajax is workable.
And it showed "Fail". Therefore, the ajax is not workable.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var promise =jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../getName",
dataType: "json"

});

promise.fail( function() {
window.alert("Fail!");
});

promise.done( function() {
window.alert("Success!");
});
```

May I know what's wrong with this?
And how can I bind the name get from splunk to a dropdown list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $el = $('#DropdownList');
    var url = "../getName";
    $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {

        $el.empty(); // remove old options

        $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", obj.name).text(obj.name));
        });
    } );

});
```